# Django: Save to a many-to-many field in a ModelForm's save() method?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a webblog app in Django. I currently have 2 models Post and PostMeta. Post is a standard post style model with fields such as author, title, content etc. It also contains a single many-to-many field called post_meta which is associated with my second model PostMeta. PostMeta is a simple name/value model with two fields, meta_key and meta_value.

What I'm trying to do is customize the Post model's form in the admin interface to be more intuitive. Specifically I want to abstract the creation of PostMeta associations rather than see the unintuitive select box which is redered by default for the admin. I want to instead show a text field in place of this select box where the user can enter a comma separated list of tags associated with the post. When the form is submitted I want to split the tag field's input into individual tags and save each as a PostMeta where meta_key will be set to "TAG" and meta_value will be one of the comma separated strings.

The problem I am having is I can't seem to get it to save correctly. I'm not sure if there is a problem with my syntax (I'm relativly new to python) or if there is somthing else I need to do which I may have missed. Here is a snippet of my admin.py:

```
class PostAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tags = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super(PostAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            model.save()
            splitTags = self.cleaned_data['tags'].split(',')
            for tag in splitTags:
                pm = PostMeta(meta_key="TAG", meta_value=tag)
                pm.save()
                model.post_meta.add(pm)
        return model

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Post
    form = PostAdminForm

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Any advice or suggestions on how to make this work would be great. Still learning :\

Answer (score 2):

The most immediate issue in your code is that when the `save()` method is called by the Django admin, the `commit` argument is almost always `False`. However, if you simply ignore the value of commit, you will not be able to do `model.post_meta.add(pm)` for newly created Posts, since the model will not have been created in the database yet (and hence cannot be referred to in the `Post` to `PostMeta` m2m table).

See [my answer to a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190735/ordered-manytomanyfield-that-can-be-used-in-fieldsets/3236621#3236621), which I think is also applicable in your case, and has quite a bit of code that you may find useful.