# In the Django admin, how can I filter down the options Django displays for a ManyToManyField that is part of the `fieldsets` property?

Tags: django, django-admin

Say I have models that looks like this:

```
class MyOtherModel(model.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    type = CharField(max_length=5, default='A')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    some_m2m = ManyToManyField('MyOtherModel')
```

and, in the admin, I want it to split up the `MyOtherModel` instances, based on type, to display in different parts of the screen, or with a different label, or whatever.

I'd like to be able to do something like this (like you can do with the `list_display` property of a ModelAdmin):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = MyModel
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {
            'fields': [
                ('name', 'some_m2m_type_A', 'some_m2m_type_B',)
            ]
        })
    ]

    def some_m2m_type_A(self):
        return MyOtherModel.objects.filter(type='A')

    def some_m2m_type_B(self):
        return MyOtherModel.objects.filter(type='B')
```

which, obviously, won't work, but you get the idea.

I tried overriding `formfield_for_manytomany()`:

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
    if db_field == 'some_m2m_type_A':
        kwargs["queryset"] = MyOtherModel.objects.filter(type='A')
    elif db_field == 'some_m2m_type_B':
        kwargs["queryset"] = MyOtherModel.objects.filter(type='B')
    return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

similar to what is suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228301/django-admin-how-to-customize-one-field-in-fieldsets), but Django still errors out with:

> FieldError: Unknown field(s) (some_m2m_type_A, some_m2m_type_B)
>   specified for MyModel. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class
>   MyModelAdmin.

and it errors out BEFORE it ever calls `formfield_for_manytomany()`...

Is there a simple way to accomplish what I'm after in the Django Admin?  Or is it going to require a huge overhaul, overriding templates, and other hard-to-maintain hackery?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own through model;

```
class MyOtherModel(model.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    type = CharField(max_length=5, default='A')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=50)
    some_m2m = ManyToManyField('MyOtherModel', through='MyThroughModel')

class MyThroughModel(models.Model):
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    myothermodel = models.ForeignKey(MyOtherModel)
```

Then in `admin.py`;

```
class MyOtherModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = MyOtherModel
    list_filter = ['mythroughmodel_set__myothermodel__type']
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized I hadn't made my question very clear that I was talking about the `fieldsets` property of the Admin class, not the `list_filter` property. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Troy Right I see now. Well I would suggest you give this answer a read as it's really good at describing Many2Many fields in terms of Django Admin classes; http://stackoverflow.com/a/3236621/1199464